# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined in react js

Tags: reactjs, arrays, function, object

I'm new in a react js and I want write a function that passed data as object(data is object {} )to get all q1 to q5 as price and p1 to p5 as vol finally I need to return new object ,this is my code here but have a error

```js
const myfunction = ( data ) => {
    console.log(data);
    const myData = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 1 + 1; i += 1) {
      const obj = {};
      obj.price = data['q' + i];
      obj.vol = data['p' + i];
      myData.push(obj);
    }
    return {
      name: 'ss',
      color: '#ffff',
      data: myData,
    };
  };
```

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i < 1 + 1; i += 1)` is only going to iterate once, for i = 1, so not too sure what your trying to do there

Comment: @sepideh bb can you post the parameter for the function ?. What it looks like. Is array length greater than 5 ?. If yes you only want to loop through first 5 items right ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you are looking for

```
    const myfunction = ( data ) => {
 
    const myData = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i ++) {
      const obj = {};
      obj.price = ['q' + i];
      obj.vol = ['p' + i];
      myData.push(obj);
    }
   console.log(myData)
    return {
      name: 'ss',
      color: '#ffff',
      data: myData,
    };
  };
  
 let myNo =  myfunction({})
 
 console.log(myNo)
```

**The solution:**

1. You need to loop 5 times
2. You don't need obj.price = data['q' + i]; this means you are accessing the index to assign a value but there is no value in your array with that index.

Hope it helps